# View State vs Server Load with Binding multiple gridviews in Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, .net, viewstate

There are 3 grid views.(one is filtered with search functionality and other two are just data bound)

View state disabled for all the three to lessen server resources.

Problem:
after performing filtering on 1st grid, remaining two are loosing its bound data.

which are the following are best alternatives?

1. Bind remaining two grids manually for every page load.
2. just enable view state independently for the remaining two grids.
3. any other suggestions apart from 1 and 2.

Comment: The view state on GridView is critical because they keep a lot of information's, like the current index, the current page, what is edit, etc. For me you can not close the viewstate on gridview. You can close it in a repeater, but not on gridview.

Comment: @Aristos please see that what if the 1st grid is dependent on search oriented results instead of edit.

Comment: The grid view is not keep the data on the viewstate but other informations.